# Referencing Sprites/ Objects stored in an array

Tags: actionscript-3

After an object has been added to an array via `push()`, how can you reference the `x` or `y` value of it? For example:

```
var Test:Sprite = new Sprite();         
Test.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
Test.graphics.drawRect(0,0,10,10);
testHolder.addChildAt(genericBlock,0);
```

Comment: sorry, missed the adding of the test array out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` and `y` values of any object stored in an array can be accessed via:

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray.push(testSprite1); // First object 'pushed' into array at position 0
myArray.push(testSprite2); // Second object 'pushed' into array at position 1

myArray[0].x = 50; // testSprite1.x = 50
myArray[1].x = 100; // testSprite2.x = 100;

// To referece..
trace(myArray[0].x, myArray[1].x); // Outputs: 50 100
```

This is a great tutorial to learn how to implement arrays and manipulate all/single elements held within them:

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3arrays/

Comment: Might I suggest that you cast the array elements, for example Sprite(myArray[0]).x as Actionscript-3 is a strongly typed language.